# como extraer contenido de un blob en php

Tags: php

me gustaría extraer o abrir el archivo que guarde en mi base de datos, soy nuevo manejando 'blob' en mysql. lo que intento es lo siguiente mediante este codigo me gustaría abrir o de alguna forma crear un link a ese archivo creado ( mostrando el contenido ) es por eso que tengo una parte de codigo html. espero explicarme de buena manera.

```
 <?php

      include('conexion.php');

       $sql="SELECT * FROM tics";

        $resul=$link->query($sql);

             ?>

                <?php while($fila=$resul->fetch_assoc()):


                $t=$fila['tit'];
                $c=$fila['con'];
                $a=$fila['arch'];



                ?>



                <div class="card-body">
           <a href=" <?= $a;?>   ">  <h2 class="card-title"> <?= $t;?> 
              </h2> 
             <p>  
                <?= $c; ?> </p> </a>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    Posted on January 1, 2017 by
                    <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                </div>
            </div>




           <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: que tipo de archivo es que deseas mostrar?

Answer (score 0):

Esto iría pegado en tu php:

```
header("Content-Type:{nombre del archivo}");
echo {tu archivo, creo que en tu caso es $a};
```

#### Recomendación:

- Las variables escríbelas completas, es mala practica escribir solo una letra.